# how to use FILTER in a DAX Query

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

My data looks like this :

```
Machine Name | Producing Status | Time To | Time From 
A | ON | 3:00:00 | 4:10:00
B | ON | 4:15:00 | 5:10:00
B | OFF | 5:00:00 | 5:15:00
```

Basically i want to write a DAX Query where I can FILTER Producing Status as ON and Calculate the time difference in seconds. I have managed to do the second part and have come up with the query ABS(DATEDIFF('datasetname'[col_name],'datasetname'[col_2_name],SECOND) however i dont know where to exactly FILTER out the Producing Status!

Comment: Oh! did not think of that! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to need to wrap the measure in a [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function so you can add the filter context

So it should be CALCULATE(measure, FILTER(filter logic))

For the FILTER you are passing in the table name, then the logic

```
FILTER('datasetname', 'datasetname'[Producing Status] = "ON")
```

So it should be:

```
Measure 2 =
VAR dif =
    DATEDIFF ( MAXX ( 'Table', [Time From] ), MAXX ( 'Table', [Time To] ), SECOND )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( dif, FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Producing Status] = "ON" ) )
```

You could also create a Calculated Column with an IF Statement

```
Column = IF('Table'[Producing Status] = "ON",  DATEDIFF('Table'[Time From], 'Table'[Time To], SECOND), BLANK())
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi! i tried this before but the then there is an error in taking the columns of the dataset. It is only showing options of MEASURES created before.

Comment: Updated to use a MAXX function to iterate through the rows, please accept if OK